Microsoft Dynamics 365 Finance API SalesInvoiceV2Lines
I have a task to implement Microsoft Dy365. I did it with oData APIs.
The problem is the SalesInvoiceV2Lines endpoint does not send tax percentages, and tax code for the invoice.
I tried to get the Taxgroup from the customer and get the tax group data from another endpoint. Still, none of those endpoints return the tax percentage.

I need help to find a way to fetch tax details from Dynamics APIs
If that's not possible I would like to fetch the XML file that's generated in Dynamics 365 for e-invoice
If there is a REST API Instead of oData Please advise me on how I can get it. I only saw business central REST APIs and couldn't find anything related to Dynamics 365 Finance and operations

(I'm not attaching any codes I tried as this is not specifically code issue)


Please [edit] your question title to describe the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your current title is comprised almost entirely of the repetition of the tags (which should not be in the title at all). Your title should be clear and descriptive enough that a future site user skimming a list of search results will know what the post contains. You can find suggestions on writing a good title in [ask].
